# Remove duplicate @use statements in common theme file

Tags: scss-mixins, angular13

We are working on an angular project where we have a common theme file and separate component theme files as well. We have `@use <lib> as lb` in multiple component theme files. In common theme file, we are importing all the component themes. Now after the build, there are multiple duplicate `@use <lib> as lb` in common theme file and because of that we are getting error `SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules` .
Is there anyway we can combine or remove the redundant `@use` statements during or after the build